# Current Activity finished when I build a notification

Tags: android

I want to start a notification in current Activity (ChatActivity),when I touch the notification ,I want to enter the ChatOneActivity.

However I don't want the current Activity (ChatActivity) finished when I'm in the ChatOneActivity(Because I'm receiving the data).And when I press the back button,I want to stay in the ChatActivity.

（The point is I do not want the ChatActivity finish ,no matter which activity I am current in）.

So what should I do?

Here is the code

```
    private void showNotification(String id, String message) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext())
        .setSmallIcon(android.R.drawable.sym_action_email)
        .setContentTitle("You have a new message")
        .setContentText(message);
        Intent intent = new Intent(ChatActivity.this,ChatOneActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("toId", id);
        TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(ChatActivity.this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(ChatOneActivity.class);
        stackBuilder.addNextIntent(intent);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_CANCEL_CURRENT);
        builder.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);
        NotificationManager mNotificationManager =
                (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
        mNotificationManager.notify(1, builder.build());
}
```

Now I enter the ChatOneActivity,when I press the back button,I return to the desktop. means that the ChatActivity has already finished,which I don't want

Comment: The first thing you should do is show us some code.

Comment: _Notification can't work_ where is the code for that?

Comment: @bub what code? it just cant work.

Comment: I have add the code.Sorry

Answer (score 0):

I believe you can't do what you want.

First of all, take a look to this link https://developer.android.com/guide/components/tasks-and-back-stack.html worth a read.

[image]

You are opening ChatOneActivity from ChatActivity and it will be saved in the Back Stack, Android system can kill your activity when memory is needed but it will be recreated.

Also, you are adding ChatOneActivity as a parent in the back stack

```
TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(ChatActivity.this);
        stackBuilder.addParentStack(ChatOneActivity.class);
```

If you are in the parent activity and the back button is pressed, is reasonable that the app will close.

If you want to open Activity2 from Activity1 and when you press back return to the Activity1 you shouldn't have to do anything, the Android Back Stack will manage the behavior.